# configuring ajaxAppender of log4javascript with Django backend

Tags: ajax, django-templates, log4javascript

I am trying to configure ajaxAppender of log4javascript in DJango. I have made a file `frontendlog.json` where I want to write the logs going from the front end. This is how I write the script in `myPage.html.`

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/log4javascript.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
    var url = '/frontEndLog/';
    var log = log4javascript.getLogger("serverlog");
    var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender(url);
    ajaxAppender.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var jsonLayout = new log4javascript.JsonLayout();
    ajaxAppender.setLayout(jsonLayout);
    log.addAppender(ajaxAppender);
    window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber){
        log.fatal("Uncaught error "+errorMsg+" in "+url+", line "+lineNumber);
    };
    log.info("Front End Log");
    alert('!!')
  </script>
```

In my django urls.py I have this entry `url(r'^frontEndLog/$', 'TryOn.views.frontEndLog'),`

and in my django view I have this view function

```
def frontEndLog(request):
    LOGGER.info ("frontEndLog")
    return render_to_response('frontEndLog.json', mimetype="text/json")
```

So I expected the frontEndLog to be written in `frontEndLog.json`  in the same location as other HTMLs are found in django. However, it tells me that `XMLhttpRequest Request to URL returned status code 500`. Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong here and is this the correct way to use log4javascript in django?

Comment: I basically wanted to know whether my URL needs to go through the django framework or can I simply write the logs to a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I printed the django `request` object in `views.py`. There I was able to find the log messages in the `request.POST`. It appears in the form of a dictionary since it is `JSON-ified`. You can access the logs with this

```
clientLogs = request.POST.get('data')
```

`'data'` is the key in the `key : value` pair here. (You can easily understand that when you see the POST object).

Whether you want to print it in the views.py itself or write it to a a txt file is up to you. So all this while the logs were actually getting logged without me being able to identify it! I guess I should have read the documentation better.